# Deal with multiple response and null values

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, json.net

I'm actually trying to parse a JSON request response from my PHP web service into a c# object.

I've found some code sample using json.net and then I made this code from my Wine class :

```
public Wine(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        BottleName = (string)jObject["name"];
        Category = (string)jObject["category"];
        Prize50 = Double.Parse((string)jObject["prize_50"]);
        Prize75 = Double.Parse((string)jObject["prize_75"]);
        Prize150 = Double.Parse((string)jObject["prize_150"]);
        Prize300 = Double.Parse((string)jObject["prize_300"]);
    }
```

It's work perfectly if a have only 1 response like

```
"{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Pinot noir\",\"loc_wine\":\"",\"category\":\"Red\",\"prize_50\":\"12.800000\",\"prize_75\":\"16.500000\",\"prize_150\":\"0.000000\",\"prize_300\":\"0.000000\"} "
```

But I hav trouble when I have another Json string in my json response and I wish know how can I deal with it?

And I have sometimes null fields, how can I ignore them?

Thank you for helping ! :-)

P.S. If needed, this is how I send my datas from my PHP file :

```
      $req = "SELECT * 
      FROM  t_wine
      WHERE name= \"Pinot noir\""; // for test purpose


      $res = mysqli_query($connection, $req);
      while($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
          extract ($data);
          echo json_encode($data);

      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I have another Json string in my json response and I wish know how can I deal with it?" Do you mean your json contains more than one instance of `Wine`, or do you mean there is a second, different class in the same string?

Comment: I mean I have another instance of Wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is more than one row returned from the `mysqli_fetch` statement, then echoing the json response for each row without putting the response in an array will give you bad JSON.  You're response basically would look like this:

```
{..some data...}{...some data...}
```

So let's take advantage of the array structure of JSON.  Change your PHP code to output like an array

```
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $req);
echo "[";
while($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    extract ($data);
    echo json_encode($data);
    echo ",";
}
echo "]";
```

That will give you something like this:

```
[{...some data...},{...some data...},]
```

Keep in mind, this is rough.  You'll need to trim that last comma before the end bracket.  But that's a valid JSON array.

You'll also need to modify your C# to process the jObject as an array of objects instead of one object.

Comment: I will try what both of your wrote here, I have the feeling that this is exactly what I need Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you are trying to handle getting multiple instances of `Wine`, and you want to ignore null values in json.net, you can do this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings{ NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
                                                                               }
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Wine>>(response.ToString(), settings);
```